# How mongos select a mongod in the replica set as a shard

Tags: performance, mongodb, sharding

Does anyone know how mongos select a mongod to perform a query/insert/... ?

We have 3 shards. Every shard have 3 mongod(s) which were configurated as a replica set.

---

[More detail] 
After mongos determined which shard(maybe many shards) to perform the request by using shard key, how mongos select the right mongod(in the shard, one is primary, the other two are secondary)? Or how to direct the mongos to read from the secondary member in the shard? Is it possible? Is something like ReadPreference.SECONDARY_PREFERRED can be used?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on dba.stackexchange.com because it it not related to programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the mongos will query the slave if you do not request it to only query the master.

So if you create your MongoClient instance (to talk to mongos) like this:

```
MongoClientOptions.Builder builder = new MongoClientOptions.Builder();
...
builder.readPreference(ReadPreference.nearest()); // not the primary
...
MongoClientOptions clientOptions = builder.build();
mongoClient = new MongoClient(serverAddr, clientOptions);
```

I think you actually don't need to worry about it. The mongos will wisely choose a right mongod in a determined shard. (Actually, our DBA tell me he see the query to the slave mongod)

This opition is passed to mongos through the "flags" value in the OP_QUERY struct.
I debugged into the mongodb java drive, see the value is 4 --- which means "SlaveOK" bit is set.
Please see: http://docs.mongodb.org/meta-driver/latest/legacy/mongodb-wire-protocol/?pageVersion=106#op-query 
for more detail.

Comment: This only applies to read operations, write operations will only go to a primary

Answer (score 1):

Your `mongos` instance looks at the shard key in your query or insert. It knows which shard holds which range of the shard key. There is a technical explanation [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding-shard-key/). You can look at the output of `sh.status()` to see which shard holds which range. From each shard it will connect you to the primary replication set member.

Comment: As you said "From each shard it will connect you to the primary replication set member".  -- So I can not use something like ReadPreference.SECONDARY_PREFERRED to direct the mongos to use the secondary replication set member in the determined shard?

Comment: As I know, something like ReadPreference.SECONDARY_PREFERRED is used by the driver. The driver use this value to determine which one to connect to. Will this value be passed to mongos???

Answer (score -2):

It takes the primary member, the only one you can write to, much the same way as any other driver would.

#### Edit

To clarify I was talking about writes. All writes to a replica set whether it is inited as a shard or not will be to primary only.

This answer was given in response to the `insert` bit of:

> query/insert/...

And was given before any editing.

Comment: I think that is with a replication set. @Terry seems to be asking about shards

Comment: @Mzzl Hmm reading again I am not sure what he is asking, he says a mongod in a replica set as a shard...hmm

Comment: This is how I understand it: three shards, each consisting of a 3 member repl set. That sounds like a sensible setup.

Comment: @Mzzl it does read like that too, meh our two answers cover every possibility

Comment: @Mzzl your answer is probably more right but I dunno, he could be talking about how to select a mongod from a shard set or a mongod form a replica set, dunno, we'll find out

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have added some detail about the question.

Comment: @Terry using `ReadPreference.SECONDARY_PREFERRED` should work since like version 2.0 I believe, before then you had to set it in the mongos

Comment: Again why the downvote? I am talking about writes, you can only write to the primary of a replica set unless someone knows different?